# Working with large numbers

Tags: java, bigdecimal

When I do the following calculation `(97 ^ 23) mod 187` in Java:

```
double ret = (Math.pow (97, 23))% 187;
```

ret value is `74`. The value of `(Math.Pow (97, 23))` is `4.963064143419832E45;`

My problem is the following: the value of the expression `(97 ^ 23) mod 187 = 58`. Try to do the windows calculator. I've tried using `BigDecimal` and still can not get the value I need.

Making `(97 ^ 23)` in the windows calculator it returns `4.9630641434198319969863989680919 +45` and so much more precise.

If someone can help me, thank you very much!

Comment: @greedybuddha The one shown?

Comment: I need the value 58. @Joni helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modular power is implemented in the `BigInteger` class:

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger("97");
BigInteger x = new BigInteger("23");
BigInteger m = new BigInteger("187");
BigInteger result = a.modPow(x, m); // 97^23 % 187
```

To get the result as an int you can use the `intValue()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried factoring the problem? i.e. r = (r * 97) % 187; and repeat 23 times? Here's some pseudo-Java (I don't have a compiler nearby to verify the syntax, but I tested the logic in another language and it seems ok):

```
public static abmodn(int a, int b, int n)
{
  int r = 1 % n;
  while (b-- > 0)
  {
    r = (r * a) % n;
  }
  return r;
}
```

`abmodn(97, 23, 187)` returns `58`.

Comment: I assume you know that normally power computed by dividing power by 2 and multiplying results (`O(log power)` instead of `O(power)`)... Also - any particular reason to do `r= 1 % n` instead `r = 1`?

Comment: Alexei, my answer aimed to be informative than optimal. r = 1 % n was meant to reinforce the r = (r * a) % n pattern and solving the problem using the int type.

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect floating point computations for numbers of that size without rounding errors (see [here](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.cse.msu.edu%2F~cse320%2FDocuments%2FFloatingPoint.pdf&ei=OTrGUZiTI8PCtQaIhIG4Aw&usg=AFQjCNHpJrepRvxauNXyDF3i0NG6mw3MvA&sig2=_6cl32oPA-d6cQ8XRrV1pQ&bvm=bv.48293060,d.Yms)).
Even if you don't technically need `BigDecimal` for this, since you won't have a decimal fraction, it will still compute correctly, as with:

> import java.math.BigDecimal;
>
> public class Test {
>
> ```
>  public static void main(String []args){
>     BigDecimal bdn = new BigDecimal(97);
>     BigDecimal bdx = bdn.pow(23);
>     BigDecimal bdr = bdx.remainder(new BigDecimal(187));
>     System.out.println("bd3: " + bdr);  // bd3: 58
>  } }
> ```